# Visual Studio TypeScript settings fail on deployment

Tags: azure, deployment, typescript

After followed instructions on [here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save) for enabling TypeScript support on Visual Studio 2012, i started to get below exception on Azure deployment.

What is wrong about it ?

> Command:
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\apolyon\VirtualDirectory0\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd
>   Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\apolyon\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\ApolyonRadio\ApolyonRadio.csproj(771,3):
>   error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. An error has occurred
>   during web site deployment. Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\apolyon\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\ApolyonRadio\ApolyonRadio.csproj(771,3):
>   error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. An error has occurred
>   during web site deployment.
>   D:\kuduservice\wwwroot\bin\scripts\starter.cmd
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\apolyon\VirtualDirectory0\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do TypeScript compilation on file saves locally so i don't need to import that setting in publish time.

So adding Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" attribute on import setting as below fixed problem. This is what i found best until for better solution.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
```

Comment: For some reason, that did not work for me. Instead I changed the same line to this: <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />

Comment: This is nicer than mine. I hadn't knowledge on this script syntax. I would probably use your solution.

Comment: I used the condition Exists bit too, worked like a charm, you should add it as an answer @MortenChristiansen

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comment to Freshblood's answer, there is a more general solution:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersio‌​n)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualSt‌​udioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />`

Comment: I had to do the same for the <Import> of Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props